# hasOneThrough returns the first row not the related row

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have these tables:

`grades`:

```
id | grade
1  |   1
2  |   2
```

`services`:

```
id | service
1  | service1
2  | service2
```

`comments`:

```
id | comment
1  | comment1
2  | comment2
3  | comment3
```

`comments_services`:

```
id | service_id | grade_id(nullable) | comment_id
1  |     1      |       null         |     1
2  |     1      |         2          |     2
3  |     2      |         3          |     3
```

In `comments` model:

```
public function services(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'comments_services', 'comment_id', 'service_id', 'id')
    ->with('grade');
}
```

In `services` model:

```
public function grade(){
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Grade::class, Service::class, 'service_id', 'id', 'id', 'grade_id');
}
```

The issue is with the `grade` function is should return the related grade but it returns the first row instead.

This is the query generated:

```
select `grade_id``, `grade`, `comments_services`.`service_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `grades` inner join `comments_services` on `comments_services`.`grade_id` = `grades`.`id` where `comments_services`.`service_id` in (1, 2, 6, 10)
```

So if there are multiple comments with `service_id` in (1,2,6,10) it would return the first one.

I think the solution would be to include the `comment_id` in the query or condition with `comments_services.id`.

Also, I tried to split this relation instead of using `hasOneThrough`:

```
//comments model
public function services(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'comments_services', 'comment_id', 'service_id', 'id')
    ->with('ser');
}

//services model
public function ser(){
    return $this->hasOne(Service::class, 'service_id', 'id')->with('grade')
}

//comments_services model
public function grade(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class, 'grade_id', 'id')
}
```

This is not working either.

`CommentController`:

```
public function edit(Request $request, Comment $comment){
    return view('comments.edit', compact('comment'));
}
```

In the case of `hasOneThrough` this would be returned for all comments with grades:

```
"grade" => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "grade" => "1"
    "laravel_through_key" => 2
]
```

Comment: probably you need to use $this->hasManyThrough(Grade::class, Service::class); instead of $this->hasOneThrough...

Comment: `return $this->hasManyThrough(Grade::class, Service::class, 'service_id', 'id', 'id', 'grade_id') ` This returns multiple rows I need only the related one

Comment: `select grade_id,  grade, comment_services.service_id as laravel_through_key from grades inner join comments_services on comments_services.grade_id = grades.id where comments_services.service_id in (1, 2, 6, 10)`